# asp:UpdatePanel with an ASP.NET checkbox trigger

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, checkbox, updatepanel

What is the EventName property when I set up a ASP.NET checkbox control as an async postback trigger for an asp.net update panel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it is CheckedChanged.

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is set AutoPostback to true and if your CheckBox is within the UpdatePanel you shouldnt have any problems

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_Name" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_Name_OnCheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Then in the **OnCheckedChanged** function you can do whatever you need to do

```
protected void chk_Name_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OnCheckedChanged is the event name.  You can autogenerate the method by double clicking the checkbox in the UI, and based on the checkbox name it will generate the method which will most likely be:

```
protected void CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```